# given the start date & current date, how do i know if the current date is part of recurrence pattern

Tags: mysql

So I have a row which shows when it was created! (i.e. 12/1/2013), and I have recurring patterns with frequencies associated with it.

Frequencies are from 1 to 6 and Recurring Patterns are Daily, Weekly, Monthly, and Yearly.

So users can set up recurring like {Frequency:1, Recurrence: Monthly} or {Frequency:2, Recurrence: Monthly}

I need a query that will take the current and the created date, and see if current date falls under the frequency.

so if the Created Date: 12/1/2013, and Today: 2/1/2014, the {frequency: 2, Recurrence: Monthly} would be valid.

Comment: can you sqlFiddle.com your data? and post your desired output? This sounds like a very interesting question.

Comment: should monthly be based upon 30 days or the same day of every month? what about feb and months with 31 days?

Comment: I am going to assume every 30 days for ease of coding, but your example would be off as it would then only be valid for 1/30/14

Comment: What does the "*frequency*" represent?  E.g. does `{frequency: 2, Recurrence: Monthly}` mean that the event recurs twice/month?  If so, on what dates would it recur?

Comment: monthly should include the 31 days. frequency can be used to set up scenarios like every other month, every 2 weeks. etc. frequency 2 and recurrence monthly would mean every other months.

Comment: @Tin Tran http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495a8/2

Comment: @jmogera please see my answer with sqlfiddle below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7354e7/2/0) it uses a function that checks to see if the given date is recurring for each row in schedule

Comment: you mean with a variable, or column name in the INTERVAL (column or variable name) YEAR? yeah i learned that on StackOverflow too.

Comment: That is what I love about stack overflow you never stop learning while at the same time helping out the community

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Recurrence has days associated and is stored in the database as daily=1, week=7, month=31, yearly=365
- That you want valid or invalid returned
- That your dates are in standard mysql date format

Then the below will work:

1. To get the difference in days between two dates use the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function
2. To get the absolute value of an int use the [`ABS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function
3. To get the remainder of a dividend and divisor use the [`MOD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) function

Here is some example code:

```
SELECT
  IF(MOD((ABS(DATEDIFF(createdDate,'2014-02-01'))/days),frequency)=0,'valid','invalid') AS result
FROM
  schedule
  INNER JOIN recurringtypes ON schedule.recurringtypeId=recurringtypes.id
```

EDITED: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d055/2)

Comment: @jmogera this is because the month has to be defined as either 30 or 31 days so it would work for `'2014-03-04'` with a month being defined as 31 days. if you want it to be the same day of the month every month then you have more work cut out for ya. sorry.

Comment: SELECT
  IF(MOD((ABS(DATEDIFF('2014-01-01','2014-02-01'))/DAY(LAST_DAY('2014-01-01'))),1)=0,'valid','invalid') AS result;